# Из чего состоит Java?

Tags: java, android, java-ee

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться со структурой java
видел вот такое разделение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Возникли следующие вопросы:

**1)** Правильно я понял, что Java Core и Java SE это не одно и тоже? Всегда считал что это одно и тоже.

**2)** Как тогда отличить, что входит в Java Core, а что в Java SE? Например, исключения куда отнести? BigInteger, BigDecimal? Ну это конкретные примеры, а хотелось бы для любого примера научиться отличать

**3)** Удивило что JavaFX выделена отдельно. Все-таки более традиционно разделять на Java Se, Java EE, Java ME. Куда при таком разделении относится Java FX?

**4)** Как отличить, когда моя программа соответствует Java Se, а когда становится Java EE? Я для себя это понимаю так: в Java EE могут присутствовать все что есть в Java Core и в Java SE, но когда появляются технологии такие как JSP, JSF, Hibernate и т.д. то становится Java EE.

**5)** Куда отнести такие вещи как Tomcat, Spring? В списке технологий Java EE я их не нашел, но и на Java SE это явно не похоже.

**6)** Какое место среди этого всего занимает, и как вообще сюда вплетается Java Android?

Comment: Для полноты картины стоит добавить JavaCard - рантайм для исполнения на смарт-картах.

Comment: А еще можно вспомнить [GWT](http://www.toptal.com/front-end/javascript-front-ends-in-java-with-gwt) (пишем-то и клиента и сервер на Java)

Comment: @avp, и да и нет. Это все-таки сторонний транслятор + эмулятор ограниченного набора Java SE, а не спецификация в отличие от всего остального на диаграмме.

Comment: @Nofate, эта диаграмма только повод для разговора (вряд ли в подобном вопросе (автору, похоже, интересна общая картина) стоит ей ограничиваться)

Answer (score 9):

1. Лично я особой разницы с технической стороны между java core и se не вижу. Ссылка на оракл [Java SE Core Technologies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-137187.html).
   Разве что термины употребляются в разных контекстах. `Java core` обычно пишут в вакансиях и подразумевают начальные знания языка. Знание типов данных, синтаксиса и т.д. `Java SE` подразумевает приложения, запускаемые из командной строки. Это очень обобщенно, возможно меня поправят..
2. А зачем вам это вообще отличать?) Ну, собственно, см.п.1.
3. Про `Java SE` написал выше. `Java ME`- устаревшая платформа для мобильных устройств. Помните игрушки на nokia и siemens? `Java EE` - это, в первую очередь, набор спецификаций по разработке крупных приложений(грубо говоря, `web`), а не конкретные классы. Например, Enterprise JavaBeans или вебсокеты. `Java FX` - standalone-приложения с графическим интерфейсом (swing в FX не входит)
4. Опять же, написал выше. Java EE приложения разворачиваются в контейнере сервлетов(tomcat) или сервере приложения (glassfish, jboss). `Java SE` запускаются просто на локальной машине.
5. Tomcat-контейнер сервлетов. Spring - фреймворк, предлагающий некоторую альтернативу `java ee`. Т.е. если в соответствии со спецификацией `java ee` какую-то задачу можно решить с помощью [EJB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans), то `spring` предоставляет свой собственный подход. А разработчик в праве сам решить что ему более подходит.
6. `Android`, вероятно, можно выделить так же отдельно, как и `EE`, `ME`, `SE`. Т.е. для разработки под андроид есть свои спецификации, подходы и платформы.

Comment: Замечу, что Java ME  это не только игрушки для старых siemens-ов, но и платформа для embedded устройств, которая вполне себе развивается.

Comment: @Nofate, это просто переиспользование названия, или на ней можно поделки для сименсов запускать?

Comment: @zRrr, в Sun/Oracle чтут обратную совместимость.

Answer (score 8):

1-2) Java core это судя по всему уже устаревшее название того что на [этой схеме](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index.html) называется как Lang and Util Base Libraries и Other Base Packages. Если посмотреть документацию [Java Se 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/basic-135908.html) она отсылает к списку [Base Libraries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/index.html#base), то есть можно считать что Java core == Base Libraries. Но по большому счету это знание имеет мало пользы.

3) Интересный вопрос, смотрите [по этой схеме](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/index.html) Java Fx не входит в часть Java SE API, но входит в JDK и в целом все-таки часть Jave SE Platform.

4) Смотрите Java EE это в основном набор интерфейсов, которые реализуют другие провайдеры. Java EE не входит в JDK и нужно добавлять эти классы отдельно. На самом деле, главный критерий не то Java EE приложения разворачиваются в контейнере сервлетов или сервере приложения, а использование Java EE интерфейсов. Впрочем все это сильно размыто, так как JPA интерфейсы (на которых основан Hibernate) или Dependency Injection не использует только совсем ленивый или в Hello world приложениях. По хорошему, чистых Java SE приложений почти не осталось, с другой стороны настоящие Java EE это огромные монстры на weblogic'e или websphere. Для простоты пока у вас небольшое приложение слегка использующее Java EE (вроде Hibernate), можете считать что у вас Java SE c небольшим кол-вом EE, как только оно превращается в Enterprise монстра - чистое ЕЕ.

5) Тут сложный вопрос с одной стороны Spring поддерживает EE интерфейсы и интегрирован со многими EE решениями: JSP, Dependency injection стандарт, JPA, Hibernate и многое другое. Более того на сайте проекта сказано "Let's build a better Enterprise.", то есть в первую очередь это Enterprise решение. С другой стороны, никто не мешает использовать Spring без связок с EE технологиями или минимум таких технологий. Более того можно рассматривать Spring как конкурента Java EE, можно как симбиоз с Java EE или часть Java EE решений, все зависит от каждого отдельного случая. Так что можно сказать что Spring это и EE и SE решение, как молоток, который можно использовать чтобы построить небоскреб, а можно чтобы починить сарай.

6) Хмм, Java Android вообще отдельное место, гугл взял спецификацию Java языка и сделал свою JVM и свой язык, он в целом совместим с остальной Java, но не полностью. Оракл давно пытается засудить гугл за использование Java. Так что Android это совсем другой мир не очень-то связанный с Java SE или EE.